# Apple Vision Framework Identify face

Tags: machine-learning, augmented-reality, arkit, coreml, apple-vision

Is it possible in the Apple Vision Framework to compare faces and recognise if that person is in a picture compared to a reference image of that person?

Something like Facebook Face recognition.

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

From the Vision Framework Documentation:

> The Vision framework performs face and face landmark detection, text
>   detection, barcode recognition, image registration, and general
>   feature tracking. Vision also allows the use of custom Core ML models
>   for tasks like classification or object detection.

So, no, the Vision Framework does not provide face recognition, only face detection.

There are approaches out there to recognize faces. Here is an example of face recognition in an AR app:
https://github.com/NovatecConsulting/FaceRecognition-in-ARKit

They trained a model that can detect like 100 persons, but you have to retrain it for every new person you want to recognize. Unfortunately, you can not just give two images in and have the faces compared.

Answer (score 0):

##### Yes, you can definitely create an app similar to *FaceApp* using Vision and ARKit.

For that, you have to create a `.mlmodel` representing several photos of the same person. Additionally, in ARKit, if you wanna use reference images for simple face recognition – you need to put several reference images in Xcode's `.arresourcegroup` folder.